# DNS A record with only primary/secondary nameserver options?

Tags: domain-name-system

I just bought a domain through a domain service and they give me the following options for editing DNS records:

[image]

I'm trying to set up branded bit.ly forwarding on the domain, which asks me to set my DNS A record to point to a specific IP address.

Since I don't have an option to change my DNS A record, what do I do?  (Or is DNS A the same as primary/secondary nameserver?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That panel is asking you to provide the IP addresses of your ***DNS SERVERS***, which are going to manage the domain you registered; as it appears, you only bought a *domain*, not a *DNS service* to actually manage it.

You will need to configure your A records (and/or any record at all) for your domain *inside your DNS server(s)*. But before doing that, you'll need to actually *have* one or more DNS servers to manage it.

If all of this doesn't mean much to you, then you should use a hosting provider which provides both services: domain registration and DNS; as it appears now, you only got the former and you are lacking the latter.

Comment: Thank you.  It makes sense  Do you by chance have a recommendation for a DNS server service?

Comment: Usually, domain registration and DNS are offered together by the same provider; almost every provider offers both by default, while allowing the *option* to decouple them if you want finer control. Have you tried asking your provider?

Comment: I bought the domain from Tonic.to, which is some tiny place in the country of Tonga.  I have about 10 domains with iwantmyname.com, but the ".to" domain I purchased was $50 more from them. Also, they don't offer standalone DNS servers, apparently.  It looks like there are some free options (like afraid.org), but I'm wary of a free option for speed/uptime reasons.

Comment: I've had nothing but great success with Dyn (http://dyn.com/standard-dns/).